# Eclipse me tacha y me subraya la clase JApplet

Tags: java, eclipse

Recién estoy empezando a aprender cómo crear applets; al crear una clase pública y esta heredar de JApplet, como es debido, Eclipse me subraya en amarillo y tacha en negro la clase, ¿alguien puede ayudarme?

```
package applets;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class HolaAlumnos extends JApplet {

    public void init () {
        
        JLabel rotuloJLabel = new JLabel("Hola alumnnos");
        
        add(rotuloJLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que eso lo hace cuando es una clase desactualizada y en desuso, cuando hay otra clase más nueva que sustituye a la que estás utilizando. De todos modos, si te lo subraya en amarillo, poniendo el ratón por encima da información. Añádela a la pregunta y así se sabrá cuál es la recomendación exacta.

Comment: No sé si será por esto que Eclipse te lo marca, pero las applets no se utilizan más, de hecho ningún navegador te permite correrlas sin antes cambiar algunas configuraciones. De hecho todo awt y Swing está deprecado, y ni siquiera forma parte de los módulos incluídos por defecto en Java 9 en adelante.
Te lo digo para que no gastes tiempo en aprender algo que prácticamente ya no se usa. Si te interesa Java en el desktop, puede mirar https://openjfx.io/

Comment: @Alex Es que estoy siguiendo un curso bastante antiguo, entiendo que es por eso, saltare a otro tema y ya. Una pregunta: swing  ya esta desactualizado, solo se usa javaFX?

Comment: Sí, Swing también está deprecado. Trata de seguir un curso más nuevo, hay decenas en YouTube!

Comment: Te marca error por tu versión de JDK, inclúyela en tu pregunta, lo más probable es que uses una versión en la que se haya marcado como obsoleto el uso de Applets. Ten en cuenta que una clase marcada como obsoleta o deprecated pyuede seguirse usando en la industria más de 10 años después de que haya sido marcada como tal, como es el caso de AWT, y que en el mundo java solamente significa que ya no le meterán más trabajo a ese pedazo de código.

Answer (score 0):

Eso significa que el JApplet esta deprecated y puede desaparecer pero no hoy ni mañana puede pasar varios años y te lo avisa para que uses alguna otra clase para que tu programa en un futuro no muy lejano deje de funcionar deberá buscar alguna alternativa al JApplet